# extract and remove element with two conditions in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract some element while removing the element by condition in Array.
My code is pretty ugly and I have no idea which will be better way for readability and performance

ex)
there is array like

```
a =[1,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,1]
```

I want extract element which is grater than 2 ( element >2 ). Then I will push it into new array until length of newArray is 2.

and I need last idx which index of element after loop break point in newArray
result will be

```
a = [1,2,2,2,2,1]
newArray = [3,4]  (I want to keep order)
idx = 2
```

This is my code. But pretty ugly.

```
for (let i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
  if (array[i]> cond) {
    newArray.push(array[i])
    array.splice(i, 1)
    i -= 1
    leng -= 1
    if (newArray.length === cond) {   
      idx = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a little more readable code we can apply functional style.

```
let a =[1,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,1];
let b = [];
let idx = 0;
let filterFn = function (e) { if (b.length < 2 && e > 2) { b.push(e); ++idx; } return e <= 2; }
a.filter(filterFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer you some more faster variant of code

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1];
let newArr = [];
let max = arr.length;
let idx = 0;
let cond = 2;
let maxValue = 2;

while (cond && idx < max) {
    let value = arr[idx];

    if (value > maxValue) {
        newArr.push(value);
        arr.splice(idx, 1);
        cond--;
        continue;
    }

    idx++;
}

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
console.log(newArr); // [3, 4]
console.log(idx); // 2
```